# Cannot open database ASPNETDB.MDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, database-connection, connection-string, mdf

I used default Membership of ASP.NET. After formatting PC and installing SQL Server Managment Studio I run application, I can not access my ASPNETDB.MDF, but can access other DB.
For example, when I try to register get so error:
[image]

Connection string is so:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf; User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

How can I access ASPNETDB.MDF?

Comment: You are trying to connect to the `SQLEXPRESS` instance of SQL Server - do you **have** SQL Server **Express** installed? If not: you need to **create** your `ASPNETDB` database on the SQL Server instance that you have (as a database, accessing it using its logical database name, not the physical file name)

Comment: Mmm.. I forgot install SQL Server Express 2008. I am installing it now, then will try, if can not solve, say about it again.

Comment: Thanks, I installed it, then it works

Answer (score 0):

There should be a folder named App_Data. The database file should be created inside this folder.
What you need is make sure that the ASP.Net identity has enough access rights to this folder.